# What is object Manager In Magento 2

Tags: magento2, object-manager

I am looking at the concept of the object manager, but I didn't get any proper explanation about that. I also have gone through the below link, but they are just explaining the usage, etc..

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/object-manager.html

But I want to know what is the object manager in magento2.
Thanks in advance for your better support

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The initializing of objects in Magento is done via what is called the object manager.

The object manager itself is an instance of the `Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager` class that implements the `Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface` class. The ObjectManager class defines the following three methods:

1. `create($type, array $arguments = [])`: This creates a new object instance
2. `get($type)`: This retrieves a cached object instance
3. `configure(array $configuration)`: This configures the di instance

The object manager can instantiate a PHP class, which can be a model, helper, or block object. Unless the class that we are working with has already received an instance of the object manager, we can receive it by passing `ObjectManagerInterface` into the class `constructor`, as follows:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
)
{
    $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
}
```

> Get detailed information from https://www.vortexcommerce.com/magento-2-object-manager/

**Hope it helps!!!**